# Left join not returning null records

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I'am dealing with a pretty basic SQL query, but I cannot understand why the non matching records are not represented with the null values in right table.

I have table A and table B with a composite key and some data in table B that I know that they do not match the key in table A. However, the result set returns only rows with matching keys without non matching (null) records.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND
        a.Field2 = b.Field2    
WHERE b.Field1 IS NULL
```

I was expecting to see records from table A and those records from table B that do not match to be represented by Nulls.

EDIT************************************************************

Link with sample data and tables:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PNlyqO4mwMBOGgQnWVlduiDKaDjSaE8v/view?usp=sharing

Last record in TableB should be seen because value for Field5 differs from value in TableA.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results as _formatted text_

Comment: That *implies* that there is, therefore, a corresponding row in `TableB` for **every** row in `TableA`.

Comment: I think the simplification of your SQL Statement for the purposes of the question may of eliminated the problem, there is nothing obviously wrong about the above, so its either data, or the simplification you made for posting. Can you provide the real statement in full?

Comment: Without data it is just like simple left join theory and I can assure you know already mentioned in question. So, put sample data and expected output.

Comment: In your real SQL (assuming that's a fake to hide private data etc) check you haven't written `WHERE b.SomeOtherField = 'some value'`. Putting conditions on B in the where clause will convert it to an inner join. If B is to have conditions other than "something is null", put them in the ON instead (`A LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.id AND B.type = 'whatever' WHERE B.id is null`. Also if you're using a left join to look for nulls, you should use one of the join columns, like I did with `b.ID IS NULL`, not what you did with `b.FIELD1 is null` unless Field1 has a NOT NULL constraint (easier to use id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that you start with the records in `TableA` then `LEFT JOIN` against `TableB`. This forces the engine to *only* display records from `TableA`, with additional rows/columns from `TableB` if they match, but not records from `TableB` that aren't on `TableA`.

Either you want to reverse the join order:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    TableB b
    LEFT JOIN TableA a ON 
        a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND
        a.Field2 = b.Field2    
WHERE 
    a.Field1 IS NULL -- records from A table shouldn't exist
```

Or as `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM TableA a RIGHT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND
        a.Field2 = b.Field2    
WHERE a.Field1 IS NULL  -- records from A table shouldn't exist
```

Or a `FULL JOIN` if you want records from both displayed, even if no match on the other table (no `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM TableA a FULL JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND
        a.Field2 = b.Field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL assumes inner join when you put is null check to where clause. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND
        a.Field2 = b.Field2 AND
        B.Field1 is null and B.Field2 is null  <== Added.
```